# Double arrows on js console log in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, console.log

I noticed a double arrow console log from the code below in the console. What does this mean? I'm worried that this is a bug and that the data traced is corrupted some how. Does some one know what the double arrow means and Why im getting it?

[image: The double arrow console log]

```
LoginDispatcher.register(function(payload){

  var action = payload.action;
  var text;
  log.trace(action);

  switch(action.actionType) {
    case AppConstants.LOGIN:
      setUser(action.data);
      break;
    default:
      return true;
}

LoginStore.emitChange();

return true;

});
```

When inspecting the call it looks allright.
[image: Inspection result]

Opening the folding arrows I see the following info

[image: Image of the console log with info]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this is the default behaviour of the console.log.trace function. So there was nothing wrong.